# When to use out arguments rather then a return value

Tags: function, oop, return-value, allocation, out

While going through some public API's (for instance [android.view.View.getLocationOnScreen](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen(int[]))), I noticed that it's quite common to use an approach of `void` function with `out` parameters rather then simply returning a value.

I see the benefits of this approach when there are multiple return values, and it doesn't make sense to create a dedicated complex type to hold them. It is also useful in OOP when a function returns some interface and the user is allowed to choose the implementation most suitable for his case.
In many of the examples I have seen (the one above for instance), this was not the case.

Other then such two specific cases, I see only drawbacks with such approach:

It tends to be confusing for rookie developers / users.

Every caller must allocate the `out` parameters memory on its own, which leads to code duplication and possible slippery bugs.

It requires the function to perform extra checking for uninitialized `out` parameters and decide a default behavior when it's not initialized (internal initializing / throwing exception / returning empty or default value).

So, can you think of any benefits, or a general criteria for cases that should return `out` values?

Comment: The example you give isn't pure-out as the array is used as input as well as output. It would therefore optimise in not allocating a new array, assuming that the pairs were often in arrays to begin with (if the calling code had to allocate every time before calling then nothing is gained).